# How can I add new options to a product attribute from a helper in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, helper

I have a product attribute 'test' of with a type 'int' and input 'select'.

I'm trying to add new options to it from within a helper.

It seems like the following code should do this for me but it doesn't.

```
$option = $this->_optionFactory->create();
$option->setLabel('new_label');
$option->setValue(1);
$option->setSortOrder(0);
$this->_optionManagementFactory->create()->add(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'test', $option);
```

In the above code 
`$this->_optionFactory` is`\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\OptionFactory`

and `$this->_optionManagementFactory` is `\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\OptionManagementFactory`